# Displaying a large amount of words

Tags: html, ajax

I'm developing a flash card app with a database of more than 10,000 words. What I'd like to do is display all the words and have the following three options.

1. Display as column, which would look something like

```
    +--------------------------------+
    |  A       |  word 4  |  C       |
    +--------------------------------+
    +--------------------------------+
    |  word 1  |  B       |  word 7  |
    +--------------------------------+
    +--------------------------------+
    |  word 2  |  word 5  |  word 8  |
    +--------------------------------+
    +--------------------------------+
    |  word 3  |  word 6  |  word 9  |
    +--------------------------------+
```

2. Display as table categorised by part of speech, which would look something like

```
    +---------------------------------------+
    |  Nouns   |  Infinitive  |  Adjective  | ...
    +---------------------------------------+
    +---------------------------------------+
    |  word 1  |  word 1      |  word 1     | ...
    +---------------------------------------+
    +---------------------------------------+
    |  word 2  |  word 2      |  word 2     | ...
    +---------------------------------------+
    +---------------------------------------+
    |  word 3  |  word 3      |  word 3     | ...
    +---------------------------------------+
```

3. Display as table categorised by details, which would look something like

```
    +------------------------------------------+
    |  words   |  P.O.S      | last seen       | ...
    +------------------------------------------+
    +------------------------------------------+
    |  word 1  |  Noun       |  1 day ago      | ...
    +------------------------------------------+
    +------------------------------------------+
    |  word 2  |  Adjective  |  2 months ago   | ...
    +------------------------------------------+
    +------------------------------------------+
    |  word 3  |  Adverb     |  30 minutes ago | ...
    +------------------------------------------+
```

I'm looking for a way that effectively achieves this.

- Should I load all the words in three separate div containers (giving a total of 30,000 + words) and toggle the display property between them?
- Should I delete all the words in the current displaying div container and use ajax to re-add the words to the required div container?

Or is there a way to load the 10,000+ words once and then reorganise them accordingly?

How should I approach this task?

Note I'm not looking for a coded solution.

Comment: 30,000 words at once seems like a lot to display at once.

Comment: I wouldn't be displaying 30,000 words at once. It would be 30,00 words added to the webpage but only 10,000 would be display. at once. what I'm wondering is if this approach is efficient or has is a task like this usually achieved?

Comment: As usual, it depends, and the best way to decide among the approaches is to try them and see which one works better for you.

Comment: check this out [datatables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: It really depends, it is a personal opinion, the hard part is how are you seperating them and noting that "word 1" is a noun and "word 2" is a verb? How you lay out the data to start determines how you do things.

Comment: All the words are stored as objects in a database. so determining whether it's a verb or a noun is simple.

Comment: So dynamically load what you need.

Comment: As in the Ajax option? but in the end if the user switches between all three option there will be 30,000 words added to the webpage anyways.Would this slow down the user experience?

Answer (score 0):

Create the table with low number of rows (but it should be enough to fill the screen two times because of scrolling). On scroll move the table to position where user can see it and fill it with data.

Comment: I don't think lazy loading the data and keeping them on the dom is a good idea